# How can I have a H2 and a HR tag in-line without using bad practice?

Tags: html, css, inline, html-heading

so I want to make a HR and a H2 element display on the same line, so that it looks like this:

http://gyazo.com/7943d8d8b6d23ebffc80a60c0acc872f

But it looks like this:

http://gyazo.com/30f80e33d627e7bbedf56565afbd5509

And here is the code:

```
hr {
display:inline-block;
width:60%;
float:right;
margin-right:20px;
height:5px;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

<h2 class="minecrafter" style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px;letter-spacing:3px;">Miners Union</h2> <hr>
```

Now I know I can easily fix this by having the HR tag infront of the H2 tag, but I know that this is bad practice and I don't think it will work in xHTML.

Thank you for reading and any replies :)

Edited to correct typo as pointed out

Comment: `inline-block` should not contain spaces in your CSS. Typo?

Comment: It seems there was a typo but it hasn't fixed it after changing, but thanks for pointing that one out!

Comment: Those links tell me I have to download something. Stackoverflow supports images. Use them please.

Comment: You must use `border-color` as well.

Comment: Why would having the HR before the H2 be bad practice? On the contrary, since the headline will presumably have content after it that it is the headline for, having the HR _between_ the headline and that following content would make _less_ sense, than having it the other way around. And why wouldn’t that “work” in XHTML? Your whole “reasoning” seems to be based purely on guessing, and not any kind of noteworthy knowledge about the topic.

Comment: @Jonathon Wood, you don't have to download anything.  Its just a url to a picture.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel thanks, didn't think about that one.

Comment: @CBroe please forgive me, when it comes to web design I am a beginner.  in XHTML I thought it had to be much cleaner to not come up with arrows, as the tags have to be in the right order etc.  I have researched this before and a lot of places said it was bad practice.

Comment: @TobiasYeomans That is a quirk with `<hr>`s. You have to set both the background color and the border color, or it will look different in the varioous browsers. For example, Chrome requires the border color, while IE uses the background and Firefox uses both.

Comment: hello, maybe a background image or gradient could help, so could be display:flex exemple of the idea: http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pJojXa this could work if you do not support IE8 for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use :after element like this: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/t3knpksv/)

```
h2:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3px;
    background: red;
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Also works, but it will complicate a lot of issues with other h2 tags and divs which I will have to sort out so I went for the easier option below, but still thanks!

Comment: Ok, try this `h2.minecrafter:after`

Comment: What is the :after element?

Comment: Inserts content after the selected [CSS ::after Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp)

Comment: And here it's an example if you need to use <hr> tag [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/psfvLk93/) but you need to put <hr> in your <h2> tag

Comment: Ohh makes sense, is there any benefits to using this instead of just putting display:inline-block; in both the h2 and hr?

Comment: Yes, it make that you use less HTML and the load time of the site will be less and your code will be more clean (very important for me :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by changing your css to:

```
hr, .minecrafter {
    display: inline-block;
}

hr {
    width: 60%;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added display:inline-block; to the style=" " on the h2 tag as to not complicate issues with other h2 tags using class.minecrafter.  Works fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<h2 class="minecrafter"><span>Miners Union</span><hr /></h2>

body {
    background: #444;
    color: #fff;
}
h2 {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h2 span {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
h2 hr {
    border: 0;
    background: #fff;
    height: 4px;
}
```

A `:after` approach would be a "cleaner" way to do it, however.

https://jsfiddle.net/0sh4a1wL/2/

Comment: you cannot insert hr in h2, but a pseudo element would do indeed : https://jsfiddle.net/0sh4a1wL/3/

Comment: @GCyrillus exactly what should be done, I messed with `:after`, and I was missing the `overflow: hidden`